# addDay() function returns wrong value in Data.js

Tags: javascript, datejs

I am using [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)  in my web app, when i subtract one day from "Mon Oct 8 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2012" , it is returning "oct 6" instead of "oct 7"

Here is my code:

```
var startTime = new Date(2012, 9, 8);
var beforeStare = startTime.clone().addDays(-1);
```

[image]

Why this is happening ? how to fix this ?

and also i tried this `new Date(2012,9,7);` it returns

> oct 6 23:00:00 UTC-0300 2012

**Note**: i am using the  `Asuncion(UTC-04:00)` TimeZone

[JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/wDF9m/)

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/wDF9m/2/ works fine. No need for clone().

Comment: The problem seems to be the timezone change.  8 Oct 2012 00:00:00 UTC-0300 minus 1 day *is* technically 6 Oct 2012 23:00:00 UTC-0400.  The problem seems to be that you're working with different timezones.

Comment: @1.44mb that is not working for the specified timezone

Comment: @Corbin, i know there is an issue. what is the solution for that?

Comment: @BalaKrishnan Timezones don't magically change themselves.  Something in your code has to be doing it.  Dates default to the environment's tz (your computer's tz), so something has to be shifting it.  Please try to make a recreatable example as a fiddle.  The one you posted behaves as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

You convert date to utc make calculations and convert to local timezone when showing to the user, this way you will make sure that all dates you are working with have the same standart.

```
// Creating the date "Oct 7 2012"
var date = new Date(2012, 9, 7);

//Convert to UTC in a safe way
var date_utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());

//Make the calculation in UTC format
var beforeStare_utc = date_utc.addDays(-1);

//Show to the user in his/her local time
var beforeStare = new Date(beforeStare_utc + " UTC");
```

​

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDF9m/3/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript dates know about exactly two timezones: local time and UTC.  You can parse a date from a third timezone, but JavaScript immediately forgets about that timezone and will only tell you about that date in terms of local time or UTC.

One day before `Mon Oct 8 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2012` is `Mon Oct 7 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2012`.  Converted to your local time of -0400, that is `Mon Oct 6 23:00:00 UTC-0400 2012`.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDF9m/6/)